# Android: Notification not working if i restart the device

Tags: android, notifications, android-manifest, push-notification, android-notifications

I have implemented the notification for my device.

It works great. But if i reboot the device it is not going to work at all.

So whats the wrong with it ?
Should i have to add anithing in manifest ?

I have added this code to receive the broadcast of notification class.

code:

```
    <!-- To receive the Alarm Notification -->
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmNotificationReceiver" android:enabled="true">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>  
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is Just the notification that display the message. And I have implemented the alarmManager to set its time of notification.

Comment: You have to BroadCast the action of Boot Completed for having the Notification.

Comment: @LalitPoptani : Yes i think something like that. Please answer me with that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a class that extends the `BroadcastReceiver` and put the `AlarmManager` code in its `onReceive` then you can resgister the `BroadcastReceiver` in the Manifest file as below.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also add the Permission to the Manifest File.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```